# Why I can't set a background image into an ImageView declared into a fragment xml configuration from the related fragment class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-image

I am absolutely new in Android development and I have some problem developing my first app.

So I have the following situation:

1. I have this **fragment_screen_slide_page.xml** file that contains the element of a fragment that is shown into a view and have to show an image when it is loaded into an activity:

   ```
    <!-- Dummy content. -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/carbonara" />

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
            style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
   ```

As you can see it contains the **ImageView** element having **id=imageView1** (where the image have to be loaded when the fragment is putted into the activity).

Then I have this **ScreenSlidePageFragment** that works on the previous fragment, I have something like this:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    ................................................................

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       System.out.println("PAGE NUMBER: "+ mPageNumber + 1);
        // Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        // Set the title view to show the page number.
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));
        System.out.println("TESTO: "+ getString(R.string.title_template_step, mPageNumber + 1));

        // Obtain the colosseum_icon.png from the rsources as a Drawable:
        Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.colosseum_icon);

        // Retrieve the reference of the ImageView element of the layout having id=imgSlide:
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page,container,false);
        ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            imgSlideView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
        } else {
                                  //imgSlideView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.colosseum_icon));
        }

        return rootView;
    }
        ................................................................
        ................................................................
        ................................................................
    }

    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    ................................................................
}
```

So as you can see, into the **onCreateView()** method I basically do the following operation:

1. I retrieve the **ImageView** element reference having **id=imageView1** declared inside the previous **fragment_screen_slide_page.xml** file.
2. I set a retrieved drawable as background of this **ImageView** doing:

   ```
    imgSlideView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable)
   ```

I expect that this image have to be shown on my screen but it don't happen. The image related to the retrieved **drawable** variable is not shown. Instead of the image appear an empty space having **250dp** as height (as specified into the XML). Under the empty image appear the expected content of the **TextView**

What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you would want to use `android:src="@drawable/carbonara"` instead of`android:background="@drawable/carbonara"` on your ImageView and you set `.setImageDrawable` instead of `.setBackgroundDrawable`

Next - `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page,container,false);` is not needed and should be removed. Instead of `ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);` it should be`ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);`

Also this of course

```
final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        imgSlideView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
}
```

is only activated is sdk is lower than Jelly Bean (I'm not sure if that applies to your test environment).

Answer (score 1):

The function inflate will generate a new view every time. you called twice, so you have two seperate view: **view and rootView**, and return rootView, so The fragment will show rootView, no view. no image.  changes like this:

```
    // Retrieve the reference of the ImageView element of the layout having id=imgSlide:
ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1)
```

Year, And more, ImageView should use android:src and setImageDrawable

Everything will be ok.

added, this code block has problem:

```
final int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
       // if your phone version below 4.1
    imgSlideView.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
} else {
                          //imgSlideView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.colosseum_icon));
}
```

if your phone, android version is bigger than 4.1 (I think so -_-|), you don't change your image. so uncomments the else code.

Comment: It still be empty :-(

Answer (score 1):

**Use setImageResource() instead of setBackgroundDrawable()**

So it should be

imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image);